# A Command Is Already In Progress

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I am attempting to run a background worker for a web app that I am developing. I am using Npgsql as my EF Core provider.

For clarification, I have injected my `DbContext` with a Transient lifetime, and have allowed Pooling in my connection string, however, whenever I try to test it I get the following error:

> Npgsql.NpgsqlOperationInProgressException: A command is already in progress: [My Query Here]

I have my `Program` Class Set up as such:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                // Get the configuration
                IConfiguration config = hostContext.Configuration;

                // DbContext
                services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(config.GetConnectionString("PostgreSQLString")), ServiceLifetime.Transient);

                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                services.AddScoped<IDTOService, BackgroundDTOService>();
            });
}
```

Which then leads to my `Worker` class

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private Logger logger;

    public Worker(IServiceProvider services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.Services = services;

        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(configuration.GetConnectionString("PostgreSQLString"));
        var context = new StatPeekContext(optionsBuilder.Options);

        this.logger = new Logger(new LogWriter(context));
    }

    public IServiceProvider Services { get; }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        this.logger.LogInformation("ExecuteAsync in Worker Service is running.");
        await this.DoWork(stoppingToken);
    }

    private async Task DoWork(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        using (var scope = Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();
            var dtoService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDTOService>();
            await dtoService.ProcessJSON(stoppingToken);
        }
    }

    public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        this.logger.LogInformation("Worker service is stopping.");
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

which leads to my `BackGroundDTOService`

```
public class BackgroundDTOService : IDTOService
{
    private int executionCount = 0;
    private Logger logger;
    private MyDbContext context;
    private DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext> optionsBuilder;

    public BackgroundDTOService(IConfiguration configuration, MyDbContext context)
    {
        this.optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>();
        this.optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(configuration.GetConnectionString("PostgreSQLString"));

        this.logger = new Logger(new LogWriter(new MyDbContext(this.optionsBuilder.Options)));

        this.context = context;
    }

    public async Task ProcessJSON(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            this.executionCount++;

            this.logger.LogInformation($"DTO Service is working. Count: {this.executionCount}");

            this.ProcessTeams();

            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), stoppingToken);
        }
    }

    public void ProcessTeams()
    {
        // Add Any Franchises that don't exist
        var franchiseDumps = this.context.RequestDumps.Where(rd => rd.Processed == false && rd.DumpType == "leagueteams");
        foreach (RequestDump teamDump in franchiseDumps)
        {
            var league = this.context.Leagues.Include(l => l.Franchises).FirstOrDefault(l => l.Id == teamDump.LeagueID);
            var teams = Jeeves.GetJSONFromKey<List<DTOTeam>>(teamDump.JsonDump, "leagueTeamInfoList");

            foreach (DTOTeam team in teams)
            {
                this.UpdateFranchise(team, league);
            }

            this.logger.LogInformation($"DTO Service Processed League Teams on count {this.executionCount}");
        }

        this.context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

The error appears to occur immediately after snagging `franchiseDumps` when it tries to get `league`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Could you try materialising the query:

```
 var franchiseDumps = this.context.RequestDumps.Where(rd => rd.Processed == false && rd.DumpType == "leagueteams").ToList();
```

Comment: Oh that seemed to work! Is there a reason why Npgsql needs that where other providers don't?

Comment: If you do foreach over an EF Core LINQ query, you're keeping the reader open and streaming results. That means that if within the foreach you perform another query on the same context, you're effectively doing multiple commands on the same connection, which isn't supported.

Comment: My guess is that the "other providers" where this works is SqlClient with MARS (Multiple Active Result Sets), which is precisely this feature. Npgsql doesn't support MARS (and for good reason), the right solution here is either to materialize the list as suggested, or if it's too big for that, use two contexts (although that brings in its own problems).

Comment: It's as @ShayRojansky mentioned, you can't run multiple commands over the same connection at the same time.

Comment: This helps a ton! Thanks. I'll look into implementing a separate context for each class/method

Comment: Materializing the query works to me: var query = context.Projects.Where(p => p.Stateid == (int) Components.Enumerators.ProjectState.Active).ToList();

Comment: @ShayRojansky hi just stumbled upon your explanation here, could you explain a bit more about the reason this answer works? From your comment, is the second sentence of first comment an explanation of if you 'dont' or 'do' use LINQ? I think I'm misunderstanding, thx.

Comment: @Ian004 it's a matter of whether your underlying database provider (SqlClient vs. Npgsql) support having more than one database command (DbCommand) executing at the same time (on the same connection (DbConnection)). SqlClient supports this when the MARS feature is activated, Npgsql does not. The way you write your LINQ queries impacts whether EF Core attempts to start multiple commands on the same connection.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and I realized that `PostgreSQL` doesn't support `Multiple Active Result Sets` (MARS) compare to `MSSQL`.

An alternative way that worked for me to fetch objects with foreign key:

```
IEnumerable<Expense> objList = _db.Expenses;
foreach (var obj in objList.ToList())
{
    obj.ExpenseCategory = _db.ExpenseCategories.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == obj.ExpenseCategoryId);
}
```

Comment: It works for me, It is not common to implement PostGreSQL when using ASP.NET